# Showing Multiplicative Inverses of Polynomials of Algebraic Elements Are Also Polynomials

Tags: galois-theory

1. Let $E$ be a field extension of $F$.
2. Let $\alpha \in E$ be algebraic over $F$.
3. Consider $a_0 + a_1 \alpha + \ldots + a_{n} \alpha^n = f(\alpha) \in F[\alpha]$.

How can I show that $\frac{1}{a_0 + a_1 \alpha + \ldots + a_{n} \alpha^n} \in F[\alpha]$?

I have tried to think about the simpler case of just showing that $1/\alpha \in F[\alpha]$ but haven't been able to come up with anything.  I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that if $F$ is a field then $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain with respect to the degree map.

Let $\beta = a_0 + a_1\alpha + ... + a_n\alpha^n\neq 0$ be the element we are interested in finding the inverse of. Then there is a corresponding polynomial $\beta(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + ... + a_n x^n$ in $F[x]$.

Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$. Now we may assume the degree of $\beta(x)$ is less than the degree of $m(x)$ since if $\beta(x)$ contained higher powers of $\alpha$ we could use the minimal polynomial to replace these powers with smaller powers of $\alpha$.

Now the fact that $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, along with the fact that $\beta(x)$ and $m(x)$ must be coprime ($m(x)$ is irreducible and $\beta(\alpha)\neq 0$) tells us that there exist polynomials $a(x),b(x)\in F[x]$ such that:

$a(x)\beta(x) + b(x)m(x) = 1$.

Substituting $x=\alpha$ tells us that $a(\alpha)\beta = 1$ and so we have found our multiplicative inverse $a(\alpha)\in F[\alpha]$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $\;f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n\;$ be **the** minimal polynomial of $\;\alpha\neq 0\;$ over $\;\Bbb F\;$ . Then $\;a_0\neq 0\;$ (why?) and also

$$a_0+a_1\alpha+\ldots+\alpha^n=0\implies a_0\alpha^{-1}+a_1+\ldots+ \alpha^{n-1}=0\implies$$

$$\alpha^{-1}=-\frac1{a_0}\left(a_1+a_2\alpha+\ldots+\alpha^{n-1}\right)\in\Bbb F[\alpha]$$

Comment: $a_0 \ne 0$ because if it were, then one could factor out an $\alpha$ from the minimal polynomial -- contradicting its irreducibility.

Comment: Indeed so, @user1770201

Comment: Taking this route to answer the problem, why is it that $\alpha^{-1} \in F[\alpha]$ implies that the inverse of *any* polynomial is in $F[\alpha]$?

Comment: Well, the above is the step you wanted to do first. After this you can try some induction or else try the way fretty wrote.